# alternatives to using a elif stament python

Tags: python

Im trying to find a cleaner way to do this. 
I have around 20 different currency pairs and backing there data up to a monthly csv file now I would like to generate a name automatically in regards to what your currancy is set to. To assigning the custom name and data to the name but rather than having a insanely long elif statement i am looking for a simpler cleaner why to do this

using VS community
with Python 3.7

```
import datetime as dt
import csv

currency="USD/JPY"
format="csv"

##  Find Currancy Name
if currency == "EUR/USD":
    currencyName = "EUR_USD-"
elif currency == "USD/JPY":
    currencyName = "USD_JPY-"
elif currency == "GBP/USD":
    currencyName = "GBP_USD-"
else:
    currencyname = "not found"

currentDT = dt.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m')
DatabaseName = currencyName + currentDT
print(DatabaseName)
```

Comment: `currencyName = currency.replace('/', '_') + '-'`…?!

Comment: Thanks deceze dis helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a dictionary to get a `O(1)` lookup instead:

```
d = {"EUR/USD":"EUR_USD-","USD/JPY":"USD_JPY-"}
value = d.get(currency,"not found")  # "not found" is the default value
```

as stated in comments, in that case, it seems that a simple `str.replace` could do the job. A dictionary can perform generic lookups.

Comment: Thanks Jean-François Fabre i'm still learning python was looking better understanding on the result i got in google